# MYSQL Finding how many users transacted per month

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-workbench

I have been tasked to find how many users performed a transaction in every month in 2020
I know i have two tables to work with.

```
Table Name: Receipts|Columns: receipt_id, collection_id, user_id, amount
Table Name: Games |Columns: game_id, collection_id, game_date_time
```

i tried this but I dont think it makes sense or works

```
select  month(games.game_date_time) AS Month, sum(receipts.id) from bills
join games on bills.collection_id =  games.collection_id
WHERE YEAR(games.game_date_time) = 2020 
group by receipts.user_id, month(games.game_date_time)  
order by month(games.game_date_time)
```

Comment: `sum(receipts.id)` doesn't make much sense. IDs are just arbitrary numbers, it doesn't make sense to add them.

Comment: *how many users performed a transaction in **every** month in 2020* Nobody performs a transaction in December, 2020 - so simple `SELECT 0;`.

Comment: @Akina Don't be so pedantic, they obviously mean "each" month. Most people use those words interchangeably and context makes it clear. The OP might not even be a native English speaker, so give them some slack.

Comment: Is `bills` supposed to be `receipts`?

Comment: @Barmar *Most people use those words interchangeably and context makes it clear.* Most people do not think carefully until you ask the question similar to my "pedantic" one. For example, can you tell does current month must be taken into account? or only previous, "finished", months, must?

Comment: @Akina It's a pretty safe bet that OP meant whichever 2020 months are in the DB, regardless of whether they're in the past, present, or future.

Comment: @kmoser transactions - in future? seriously? what if the financial inspector comes?

Comment: You've never heard of test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` to get a count, not `SUM()`. And if you want a count of users, without counting the same user twice, use `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`, don't put `user_id` in the grouping.

```
SELECT MONTH(g.game_date_time) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT r.user_id) AS users
FROM receipts AS r
JOIN games AS g ON r.collection_id = g.collection_id
WHERE YEAR(g.game_date_time) = 2020
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: This query tells how many users pays in each separate month. But tells nothing about who pays in all months.

Comment: That's how I understood the question. You saw my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

> find how many users performed a transaction in every month in 2020

```sql
SELECT COUNT(r.user_id)
FROM receipts AS r
JOIN games AS g USING (collection_id)
WHERE YEAR(g.game_date_time) = 2020
GROUP BY r.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(g.game_date_time)) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

This query:

1. Selects rows for current year only.
2. For each user - calculates the amount of distinct months for payments for this user and compares with current month. If user has payments in each month (including current!) these values are equal.
3. Count the amount of users matched this condition.

PS. The query will fail in 2021 - for to receive correct info in future use

```sql
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(g.game_date_time)) = CASE YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                                                 WHEN 2020
                                                 THEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
                                                 ELSE 12
                                                 END
```